# Difference b/w exec( ) and system( ) in unix

Tags: c, unix, system, exec

What is exactly the difference between commands exec(const char *c) and system(const char *c) in unix based systems ?

Both can be called from a C program to execute system calls. Is there a difference b/w the two ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`exec` replaces your process with the specified program.  Your program is done, and will not continue running.

`spawn` starts a new process (probably by first using `fork`), and runs the specified program while your program continues executing.

`system` starts a new process (probably by first using `fork`), and runs the specified program while your program waits.  Once the child exits, your program continues.

Comment: `system` also runs the command under the shell, as in `/bin/sh -c "command"`.  Pretty big difference if the command contains funny characters.

Answer (score 1):

`exec` will execute a file, while `system` will execute a shell and feed it with the arguments.

From wikipedia:

> It (system) differs from the exec/spawn family of functions in that instead of passing arguments to an executed object, a single string is passed to the system shell, typically the POSIX shell, /bin/sh -c.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_%28C_standard_library%29

Comment: It won't execute a console, just a shell.